# How a non-immediate parent can affect its non-immediate child elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, css-specificity

So, I'm a newbie and using bootstrap v5 to create a navbar with the below Html code. Here, the immediate parent(ul) of my link items has a class of "navbar-nav" which styles my link items as stack on top of each other. Then the non-immediate class "navbar-expand-lg" styles my items as adjacent to each other. Now I'm confused about how this non-immediate class affected my items and with which property mentioned in the bootstrap CSS file.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
<ul class="navbar-nav ">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of **CSS selectors and specificity**...

Bootstrap has more specific CSS for `.navbar-expand-lg` that makes the inner `navbar-nav` change to `flex-direction: row`. This overrides the `flex-direction: column` from `.navbar-nav`.

From Bootstrap 5 CSS...

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/RqhOi8q9qE)